# How can I transform the string of characters back into words?

Tags: python-3.x

I've been trying to learn Python for the past two months or so, but I'm really only now getting my hands dirty with it, so I thank you in advance for your patience and insight.

I was working on a project where I was cleaning the names in a dataset. That means filtering out the names of the apps who have foreign characters (that is to say, ord(character) > 127.

However, it turns out that this approach removed too many legitimate apps since the emojis in those were coming back as out of that range.

The workaround is to allow up to one foreign character. So it's pretty straightforward for that part; I can simply scan the characters of the names in each list. The part I'm having trouble with is telling Python where in the loop to add a name to the "cleaned" list (the final version of app names having <=1 one error. (The requirements are actually different in my project, but I'm trying to keep it as simple as possible in this example.)

To simplify the problem a bit, I was working on a dummy list. I have included that for you.

Where do I add the code so that after that final iteration of each name, the name is added to the list entitled cleanedNameList to only append names with <=1 foreign character?

When I've tried appending a 'clean' name to the list before (a name that had <=1 foreign characters in it), it also sometimes adds the ones with more than three foreign characters. I think this is due in part to me not knowing where to put the exception counter.

```
nameList = ['うErick', 'とうきhine', 'Charliと']
cleanedNameList = []
exceptions = 0


for name in nameList:
  print('New name', name, 'being evaluated!')
  exceptions = 0
  for char in name:
    print(char, 'being evaluated')
    ascii_value = ord(char)
    if ascii_value < 127:
      continue
    elif ascii_value > 127:
      exceptions+=1
      print(exceptions, 'exception(s) added for', name)
#where would I add append.cleanedNamesList(name) ?
```

So, TL;DR: how do I scan a list of names, and once done scanning the list, add those names to a new list only IF they have <=1 foreign character.

Comment: Do you want to disallow names that have more than one foreign character, or do you want to sanitize names, so that they have at most one foregn character?

Comment: I would like to append only names that have <=1 foreign character to the final list. :) Thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
def canAllow(s):
    return sum((1 for char in s if ord(char)>127), 0) <= 1

cleanList = [name for name in nameList if canAllow(name)]
```

Comment: That was so simple and elegant. Thank you, sir! I'm assuming that 0 in the function means that it can be 0, as a failsafe? Thanks again

Comment: Exactly that. `0` is what you get when the sequence it has to sum over is empty

Comment: Although it may be simple and elegant code, it would be a better answer if it contained an explanation.